# `adb shell mv` moves files but app doesn't work anymore, while it works if I move the same files via file manager

Tags: adb, file-system, shell, file-management

I try to move account-related files/directories of an app (for account changing purposes) via `adb shell mv`. Moving the files works great, but the app hangs while loading/login.

If I move the files manually via files manager, there is no problem at all (I move the files from `/data/data/com.example.app` to `sdcard` and move the same files from another account back to the app folder) -> everything works fine, the app is loading, the account is logged in and changing accounts works without any problem.

If I move the files via `adb shell mv`, the app is stuck while loading. If I move the files to `sdcard` via `adb shell mv` and move it back with the file manager, it also works fine. But if I move the files from `sdcard` to app folder, it doesn't work.

I also tried copying the file via `adb shell cp -r` but got the same problem.

Does anybody have an idea what's the problem or how to fix this problem? Does `mv` corrupt the files? But if it would corrupt the files, it wouldn't work if I moved it to `sdcard` via shell `mv` and moved it back via files manager.

---

It seems like Robert is right, the file group changes:

Folder original:

```
drwxrws--x 8 u0_a295 u0_a295_cache 3452 2024-01-31 10:30
drwxrwx--x 3 u0_a295 u0_a295       3452 2024-01-31 10:31
```

Folder after moving:

```
drwxrws--- 10 u0_a218 media_rw 3452 2024-01-31 10:33
drwxrws---  4 u0_a218 media_rw 3452 2024-01-31 10:33
```

Files original:

```
-rw-rw---- 1 u0_a295 u0_a295    1229 2024-01-31 10:32
```

Files after moving:

```
-rw-rw---- 1 u0_a218 media_rw    1229 2024-01-31
```

Answer (score 3):

Your main problem is that you move files and folder between special sections of the file-system: from app-private folder where only the app has access to `/sdcard` a special folder where you can not execute something and all files/folders are assigned a special group `media_rw`.

For understanding why the app-private folder works you need to know that Android created for every app an own user account, in your example all app-private files and folders are owned by user `u0_a295` and group `u0_a295` / `u0_a295_cache`.

If you move the files to `/sdcard` the group is changed to `media_rw` as the sd-card section enforces this. If you later move back the files to the app-private folder the group `media_rw` remains and the files and folders have a changed owner-user and owner-group.

To correct that you can execute

```
chown -R u0_a295:u0_a295 /data/data/<app-package name>/files/
```

Note that if you uninstall and reinstall the app or try the same with a different app the user and group name will be different (not `u0_a295`).